# What is the best way to make a cross contract call on Ink!

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node, cross-contract-call

I found 2 ways to make cross contract calls on ink!.

1. The first is in this link [here](https://ink.substrate.io/basics/cross-contract-calling/) where another contract is called directly,
2. The second is in this link [here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/examples/delegator/lib.rs) where a reference(ref) is being used.

I am curious to know which is the best practice or is there any other better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point one is deprecated, and you can use only the second right now.

In the future ink! will [support `dyn Trait` notation](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/631). So you will be enough to have a trait to do cross-contract calls. Right now `OpenBrush` provides that feature via [wrapper](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts#wrapper-around-traits).