# PSP22 cross-contract call to get metadata such as token decimals and token name using ink!

Tags: ink, token, openbrush

I have a little problem here.
I have the address of a contract (PSP22 token) with the {}Ref associated with it.

I want to make a cross-contract call to get the decimals of the contract.

Its Ref is `use lp_token::LpTokenRef;`

Wondering how I can call another contract using an already deployed address to get the metadata such as `psp22Metadata::tokenSymbol()` and so on.

Comment: you can use wrapper from openbrush, [have a look this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4779/2844)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example of using the `*Ref` pattern to call another contract, given its `AccountId` in this Bulletin Board example [link](https://github.com/Cardinal-Cryptography/bulletin-board-example/blob/main/contracts/bulletin_board/lib.rs#L452) from Aleph Zero network.

Answer (score 1):

Ink has a great example in the repo's [examples folder](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples) called the [Delegator](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/delegator)

Its 4 contracts that all work together. The delegator even instantiates the other contracts then calls them later. Looks pretty cool.

Comment: I understand. I do not see any as robust as PSP22 token metadata interaction. Do you have a direct example that shows how to get the metadata of a PSP22 token from another contract, say using psp22Metadata::tokenSymbol() or a similar approach?