# Cross-contract instantiation failed with TransferFailed

Tags: ink, cross-contract-call

I am getting an error attempting to deploy my delegator smart contract. Not sure how to debug this issue.

I use the [deploy.sh](https://github.com/michaelassaf/liquid-staking-sc/blob/main/deploy.sh) to upload all smart contract code hashes and pass it afterwards to the instantiate cargo command to deploy the delegator contract. I copied this script originally from the `ink-examples` repository.

Here is the error I get when attempting to instantiate the [delegator contract](https://github.com/michaelassaf/liquid-staking-sc/blob/main/lib.rs)

```
$ cargo contract instantiate --manifest-path=Cargo.toml -x --suri //Alice --args 0 0 0x2dc77005d1e64e51910fec8553abeb84d40bd28b1b7871e317e6ee062fe6a236 0x5138b191f83404c1a8d1c1c2a965558aa413868cae54be657d5522f4942c1b41 0xfd7c89608968d6da96747ea70f92909656982832818b227dfd99b74252741a24

 Dry-running new (skip with --skip-dry-run)
          Result ModuleError: Contracts::ContractTrapped: ["Contract trapped during execution."]
    Gas Consumed Weight { ref_time: 1866330052, proof_size: 86246 }
    Gas Required Weight { ref_time: 5231342013, proof_size: 646971 }
 Storage Deposit StorageDeposit::Charge(8060300000000000000)
   Debug Message panicked at 'Cross-contract instantiation failed with TransferFailed', /home/snowmead/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_env-4.2.0/src/call/create_builder.rs:260:17
```

Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/michaelassaf/liquid-staking-sc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following changes to the endowment parameter value fixed the problem. it would be good to know what endowment is and why it made my build fail. [endowment](https://docs.rs/ink_env/4.2.0/ink_env/call/struct.CreateBuilder.html#method.endowment) documentation is really not clear.

`.endowment(total_balance / 4)` to `.endowment(0)`

```
let accumulator = AccumulatorRef::new(init_value)
                .endowment(0)
                .code_hash(accumulator_code_hash)
                .salt_bytes(salt)
                .instantiate();
```

Comment: [hear is the explanation of endowment](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4779/2844)

Comment: thanks, that solved the issue i encountered too when i tried to convert the basic-contract-caller example to use https://use.ink/basics/cross-contract-calling#builders